# Admob Interstitial ad is not clickable in android app exit

Tags: android, android-activity, admob

I am trying to show admob interstitial ad at the end of the application when user presses back button from the main activity. Ad is shown, but the ad is not clickable. My code is

I put loading part at the activity onCreate :

```
        interstitial = new InterstitialAd(getApplicationContext());
        interstitial.setAdUnitId("Ad UNIT ID");

        // Create ad request.
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
                .addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR).build();

        // Begin loading your interstitial.
        interstitial.loadAd(adRequest);
```

and in OnBackPressed :

```
@Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        super.onBackPressed();
        displayInterstitial();
    }

  protected void displayInterstitial() {
    Log.d(TAG, "start displayInterstitial()");
    if (null != interstitial && interstitial.isLoaded()) {
        Log.d(TAG, "displayInterstitial() loaded");
        interstitial.show();
    }
    Log.d(TAG, "end displayInterstitial()");
}
```

Can anyone please help me to fix this issue?

Comment: Problem may be that you call `super.onBackPressed` before `displayInterstitial()`. Try implementing an AdListener and call the super.onBackPressed from the onAdClosed instead. Or actually just calling super.onBackPressed after displayInterstitial might work, give it a try.

Comment: Calling super.onBackPressed after displayInterstitial() didn't help. I can't call super.onBackPressed inside adlistener's onAdClosed method, since it is associated with onBackPressed super class method.

Comment: Do it like this inside AdListener: `MainActivity.super.onBackPressed();`

Comment: MainActivity.super.onBackPressed() showed an error. I tried with MainActivity.this.onBackPressed(), but i got the same issue. I even tried without super.onBackPressed in the onBackPress method. That also didn't fix the issue.

Comment: What is "an error"? More details please. You mean a compile error? If you have implemented the AdListener as an anonymous inner class of the MainActivity then you _can_ call MainActivity class methods by `MainActivity.this` or super class methods with `MainActivity.super`. Anyhow, since I see you only want to show banner before app closes, why not just call `finish()` method of the MainActivity in the AdListener instead?

Comment: onBackPressed is not accessible using MainActivity.super . As i said even without super.onBackpressed also didn't work. So the error is not related to super.onBackPressed. If you have any working example for putting ads on the exit of the application, please share with me.

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way would be:

```
        interstitial.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAdClosed() {
                finish();
            }
        });
```

However, in my opinion it is better to stay at your app for a sec before app finishes. That way it is more clear that this ad was still part of your app:

```
        interstitial.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAdClosed() {
                Handler handler = new Handler(); 
                handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() { 
                    public void run() { 
                        finish();
                    } 
                }, 1000);
            }
        });
```

BTW: about the comment of calling `MainActivity.super.onBackPressed();` inside the adlistener's onAdClosed: I tested it and threw an IllegalStateException. I guess that is because the moment when onBackPressed is called is too late already. But well it is anyway not needed, so forget about it. The super onBackPressed method itself is accessible from the AdListener though and will compile just fine ;-)

Comment: Hi Donfux, Thanks for spending your time. I still couldn't get it fixed.Click is still not working. Do you have any sample project in which you have implemented admob interstitial at the exit? If so, please mail me to venkat20390@gmail.com. I will check that try to find the issue in mine.

Comment: Try adding a log statement in the onAdClosed to see if it even gets called.

Comment: onAdClosed is called.

Comment: do you have any sample APK for exit ads?

Comment: I doubt it would help, there is really no magic in this. In your onBackPressed method check that you don't call super.onBackPressed anywhere. (not before, not after displayInterstitial) Now your app closing should be happen from onAdClosed.

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
   Log.d(TAG, "onBackPressed Called");

   displayInterstitial();
   //finish();
   super.onBackPressed();
}
```